# circle actions on spheres

Tags: algebraic-topology, group-actions, quotient-spaces

I'm considering the following action of $S^1$ on $S^3$:
$$
e^{i\theta}.(z_1,z_2)=(e^{i\theta}z_1,e^{iq\theta}z_2)
$$ 
It is clear that when $q=1$ the quotient space is $S^2$. Is there any description of the quotient space when $q\neq 1$? Or in general for similar circle actions on higher odd-dimensional spheres?

Thanks.

Comment: Ok, now I realized it's just weighted projective spaces...